# How to transfer UserId from middleware to current controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

I would like to know what is the best practice to transfer userId from middleware to current executing controller ?

for example I send request with bearer token to the controller as below:

```
[Route("")]
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExampleTask(AnyObject anyObject)
{
     await _anyModule.ExecuteCommand(anyObject);

     return Ok();
}
```

at the beginning request hits middleware, there I have access to `IHttpContextAccessor` from which I can read userId. I do not want to initilize `IHttpContextAccessor` in controller class, because as I know it is not good and safe practice. I would like to know how can I transfer UserId from middleware to current executing controller ? Should I create an extension class that implements `IHttpContextAccessor` and then add this middleware to the pipeline and then initialize this class in the controller class. Is it good idea?

edit:

That's how I did it.

in startup class I add to middleware two things:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddSingleton<IExecutionContextAccessor, ExecutionContextAccessor>();
```

and ExecutionContextAccessor provides required data like UserId and it is read from IHttpContextAccessor.

```
public class ExecutionContextAccessor : IExecutionContextAccessor
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ExecutionContextAccessor(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public Guid UserId
    {
        get
        {
            if (_httpContextAccessor
                .HttpContext?
                .User?
                .Claims?
                .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == "sub")?
                .Value != null)
            {
                return Guid.Parse(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.Single(
                    x => x.Type == "sub").Value);
            }

            throw new ApplicationException("User context is not available");
        }
    }
```

With that things I created abstract controllerbase that initializes IExecutionContextAccessor and assigned guid userid.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I don't see `UserId` used anywhere in that code. Perhaps you could be more explicit in where in the pipeline you need the data.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what middleware you are using. If possible add a [mcve] of the middleware, where you have the `userId`, how you have setup your middleware/pipeline and how/when you want to access the `userId`.

Comment: If you create a classic middleware class as described on [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-8.0) you can set it in the `HttpContext` instance argument of the `Invoke` method and then use it in the controller with `HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue("UserId", out var userId);`.

Comment: thanks for explanation. Is using HttpContext controller side good practice ? UserId is included in token, thats why i do not show it anywhere.

Comment: Pls correct me if I misunderstood your concerns, thanks in advance

Comment: The usage is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abstract class to get your data :

```
[Controller]
public abstract class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
    
    public int UserId => (int)HttpContext.Items["UserId"];
    ...
 }
```

Then have your controller implement it to access that property.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common practice to use `HttpContext` in Controller for accessing the current request headers, query parameters and some other information. We can definitely access the access token in the request header in Controller.

Where to put the logic to get user id inside the request header should depend. Let's say the access token should always containing the user Id or it's invalid and then return 403 error, then we could add [claim based policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to validate the claim containing user id. If user id is not necessary for all the tokens/scenarios, then we should put the logic somewhere else, for example we could create a service to validate the token and get user id, then inject this service into the controllers which requires the user Id. Since you are having a n webapi which is stateless, so I'm afraid creating a service and use it whenever it requires is an option which can be take into consideration. Here's my sample code with jwt authentication.

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = "Test.com",
            ValidAudience = "Test.com",
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is my custom Secret key for authentication")),
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    });
    
[Authorize]
[HttpGet(Name = "GetUserId")]
public string Get()
{
    var token = Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");
    var service = new GetUserFromToken();
    var userId = service.getUserId(token);
    return userId;
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("GetToken")]
public string Token()
{
    var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is my custom Secret key for authentication"));
    var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    var claims = new[] {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "user_name"),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, "user_email"),
        new Claim("DateOfJoing", "2022-09-12"),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim("role","admin"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,"admin")
    };
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken("Test.com",
        "Test.com",
        claims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
        signingCredentials: credentials);
    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}

public class GetUserFromToken
{
    public string getUserId(string token) {
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var jwtSecurityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
        IEnumerable<Claim> claims = jwtSecurityToken.Claims;
        var sub = claims.Where(x => x.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub).FirstOrDefault();
        string subValue = sub == null? "": sub.Value;
        return subValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, I already did it by `ExecutionContextAccessor` as above which is initialized in special module called SharedModule which provides access to validation service. I registered this module as singleton so now each controller class has access to this module and it returns UserId :)

Comment: it looks like that you already had the solution, that's fine.